# ASP.NET MVC Form submission not working: no errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm making a simple movies app using ASP.NET MVC, and have created a form to add data of a new customer to the database. This code works perfectly fine. However, when I use the exact same method to make a form to add a new movie to the Movies table, nothing happens when the form is submitted. There is no error, and the database isn't updated. I saw a few similar questions on here, but none of the solutions worked for me. I tried writing the code for the movies form from scratch, AND I tried copying the customer's code and changing the variable (properly, making sure everything was altered as needed)

Just in case this info is needed:

1. This code works perfectly fine for the customers table
2. There are two models: Movie.cs and Genre.cs
3. I know that in the New.cshtml file there is an input field for DateAdded, but I will automate that and automatically set it to the date at the time of the form submission, so don't worry about that.

Here's my code:

MoviesController:

```
using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Vidly.Models;

namespace Vidly.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public MoviesController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }

        public ActionResult New()
        {
            ViewBag.Genres = _context.Genres.ToList();
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var movies = _context.Movies.Include(c => c.Genre);
            return View(movies);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Movie movie)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Movies.Add(movie);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception) { }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        } 

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var movie = _context.Movies.Include(m => m.Genre).SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
            if (movie == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                return View(movie);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

New.cshtml :

```
@model Vidly.Models.Movie
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add New Movie";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Add New Movie</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Movies"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", name="Name", required = "required", autocomplete = "off" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <b>Genre</b>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GenreId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Genres, "Id", "GenreName"), new { @class = "form-control", name="Genre" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ReleaseDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReleaseDate, new { @class = "form-control", name="ReleaseDate", required = "required", autocomplete = "off" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateAdded)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateAdded, new { @class = "form-control", name="DateAdded", required = "required", autocomplete = "off" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NumberInStock)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NumberInStock, new { @class = "form-control", name="NumberInStock", type="number", required = "required", autocomplete = "off" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Movie</button>
    </div>
}


<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#DateAdded").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '2000:2021',
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
        $("#ReleaseDate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '1930:2021',
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Just in case it's needed, here's Movie.cs (the model):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public byte GenreId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date Added")]
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Number In Stock")]
        public byte NumberInStock { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Genre.cs (Genre model):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class Genre
    {
        public byte Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string GenreName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here's what you're doing wrong: `catch (Exception) { }`. You're getting errors but that code is hiding them from you. Never do that.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Movie movie)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Movies.Add(movie);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

use  this :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Movie movie)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Movies.Add(movie);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { 
             throw e;
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

to catch your error then you can fix it